# PyCharm ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version

Tags: python, pycharm

This happens when I try to pip install some packages.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in run
    session = self._build_session(options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 52, in _build_session
    session = PipSession()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 216, in __init__
    super(PipSession, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.headers = default_headers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 555, in default_headers
    'User-Agent': default_user_agent(),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 524, in default_user_agent
    _implementation = platform.python_implementation()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1498, in python_implementation
    return _sys_version()[0]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1463, in _sys_version
    repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.6 |CUSTOM| (default, Jun  4 2014, 16:30:34) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\kyzcr_000\pip\pip.log
```

I used to use Enthought Canopy and I read elsewhere this can cause issues.  Is there anyway to resolve this?

I switched my interpreter to Anaconda and it seems like none of the modules load now either.  I'm totally nonplussed.  I can't use any modules I have installed and I can't install any new ones.

EDIT: After following instructions here, I'm getting this now: [Praw "failed to parse CPython sys.version" when creating Reddit object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105255/praw-failed-to-parse-cpython-sys-version-when-creating-reddit-object)

Although some things are installing properly with that change.

```
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-0.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting setuptools (from cryptography)
  Using cached setuptools-16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: idna in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipaddress in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.4.1 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: cffi>=0.8 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already up-to-date: pycparser in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, cryptography
  Found existing installation: setuptools 14.3

Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth
```

Comment: What is `2.7.6 |CUSTOM|`? Just uninstall Python and get the real version at https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reinstalling python and pycharm from scratch.