# Can't launch jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

The screen only shows for about few seconds then disappear without launching anything, Here's what appears on the screen:

```
Jupyter Notebook (gI-env)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:/Users/user/Anaconda2/envs/gl-env/Scripts/jupyter-notebook-script.py”, line 3, in <module>
import notebook. notebookapp
File “C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py”, line 32, in <module>
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File “C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zmq\_init_.py’, line 29, in <module>
_load_libzmq()
File “C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zmq\_init_.py”, line 21, in _load_libzmq
if platform.python_implementationQ.lower() == ‘pypy’:
File “C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py”, line 1458, in python_implementation
return _sys_versionQ[ø]
File “C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py”, line 1420, in _sys_version
repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: ‘2.7.11 lAnaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)I (default, Feb 16 2016g 09:58:36) [fISC
v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]’
```

What is the error that I'm facing here?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors, please post the text of the error so that people can find it by searching, and so that blind users are not disenfranchised from "reading" the content. To your question, how did you install Anaconda?

Comment: I am sorry, I really wish I could copy the error as it only appears for less than a few seconds and I barely managed to screenshot it.
At first, I installed it using the installer from the official website and it didn't work, then I tried uring GrapghLabs but nothing changed.

Comment: Well, since you have the screenshot, you can copy the error from that... What do you mean "it didn't work"?

Comment: I updated the question, I mean that the error appeared when I launched jupyter notebook.

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34145861/2449192 (particularly the second solution)?