Other Solution for Installing pip with Python 2.6 on Windows
I have been unable to install pip in Python 2.6.  I've downloaded the bootstrap from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/get-pip.py and the attempt to install yields ther following error:
c:\users\XXXXX\appdata\local\temp\tmpyssruu\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py:344: SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for pypi.python.org has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)

  Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.python.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Jun 10 12:50:10 2025 GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', u'www.python.org'),),)}


I've scoured the web looking for alternative solutions, but nothing has worked so far.  The above looks the most promising if I could just correct the certificate error.
The only thing I can think of to fix this is to decode the base64 in get-pip.py, modify the code, re-encode and then replace that in get-pip.py.  But there is no guarantee I will be able to fix/circumvent the error.
Can anyone offer a simpler solution, PLEASE?
My other attempts at installing pip included an unsuccessful try at installing setuptools-36.8.0 so I could use easy_install to load pip-9.0.3. that I downloaded.  It wouldn't install in the correct directory.  This solution was suggested in How to install pip with python 2.6 on Windows

I ran the setuptools install from "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost" where py.exe resides.  The correct installation should have been to "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost\lib26\site-packages", but it wanted to install to "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost\lib26\Lib\site-packages".  I couldn't persuade it to do otherwise.  Setuptools command was unavailablr in python when I tried it.

I just tried again and I get the following:  C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost>py setuptools\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "py.py", line 26, in 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost\setuptools\setup.py", line 11, in 
import setuptools
ImportError: No module named setuptools

That produced the following:  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost\setuptools\setup.py", line 11, in 
import setuptools
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\EventGhost\setuptools\setuptools_init_.py", line 5, in 
import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

It's not there.  I'll try re-installing.

That's exactly what it is.  EventGhost has Python 2.6.5 packaged with it.  I've now re-installed Python 2.6.5 in that directory.  I had to rename the new executable to py.exe, but I do see the EventGhost and eg modules when I list them from the py prompt.  I am also able to import distutils in a script run from within EventGhost.  So, i'd say it installed correctly.  But I am still unable to install setuptools. ---- We really should move this to a private chat, but I'm not familiar enough with stackoverflow to initiate one.

Seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/34145861/7976758 — modified sys.version includes "Stackless" and that triggers a bug in platform.

My guess is the failure to parse sys.version is a result, not a cause.  I added a line near the top of the setup.py file in the setuptools directory that replaced the version with one shown in a clean install of Python 2.6.5.  The same exceptions occurred with the last one showing the version I set, "Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32".

"But how could that possibly work when setuptools is not yet installed?" import setuptools imports from the current directory; there is the subdirectory setuptools.

Thanks @phd for all the help.  I have resolved the issue by installing a newer RC of Eventghost that comes with a chopped Python 2.7.12.  I then installed a release of Python 2.7.12 over it, as phd suggested I do with the previous version.  I now have pip installed.   -   To clean up this thread, I am removing the volumes of exception text I posted.
