# Installing modules with pip, "failed to parse CPython sys.version"

Tags: python, pip

this is my first post, so if I'm leaving out any key information or my formatting is off, please let me know.

I'm reinstalling python on my PC, and I haven't used it since I was getting started in Enthought Canopy. I have since uninstalled canopy, and recently reinstalled python 2.7.10. I'm trying to install numpy, scipy, and a handful of similar science based packages, using the following in cmd:

```
pip install numpy
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts\pip-script.py", line 8, in <module>
from pip import main
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from pip.commands import get_summaries, get_similar_commands
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from pip.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\completion.py", line 4, in <module>
from pip.basecommand import Command
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 20, in <module>
from pip.req import InstallRequirement, parse_requirements
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .req_install import InstallRequirement
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 17, in <module>
from pip._vendor.distlib.markers import interpret as markers_interpret
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py", line 72, in load_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\markers.py", line 20, in <module>
class Evaluator(object):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\markers.py", line 48, in Evaluator
'platform_python_implementation': python_implementation(),
File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1498, in python_implementation
return _sys_version()[0]
File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1463, in _sys_version
repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.6 |CUSTOM| (default, Jun  4 2014, 16:30:34) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

I'm not sure why it's telling me my version is 2.7.6, or why it says I'm running on an AMD64 system (I'm on an x64 device). Any idea what might be going on?

I saw a post of a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105255/praw-failed-to-parse-cpython-sys-version-when-creating-reddit-object), but the suggested resolution (setting the sys.version string manually) didn't help, whenever I attempted to install, it reset itself to the one displayed above.

Again, any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: It looks like it is getting confused with the version of pip/python you had installed with canopy.  What happens if you go into the new install of python, find pip, and then run it with the explicit path instead of just calling the `pip` command?

Comment: You're exactly right, the files left over from my canopy install were interfering with the install. Easy fix, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I went through my computer and located the old install of Canopy. Once I removed the previous install of python, the issue was resolved.